# macOS Script Editor - AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

Tags: python, macos, applescript

When I run the following script on macOS Script Editor (AppleScript):

```
do shell script "bash -l -s <<'EOF'
   python3 -c 'import requests'
EOF"
```

... I get the following error:

```
error "Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py\", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py\", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py\", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File \"/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py\", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections.abc
  File \"/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/traceback.py\", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File \"/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/linecache.py\", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File \"/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py\", line 33, in <module>
    import re
  File \"/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py\", line 143, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'" number 1
```

Of course, running `python3 -c 'import requests'` works fine on bash using the terminal. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Looks like it's executing mixture of `/python2.7/` and `/python/3.7.6_1/` packages...

Comment: Note that `do shell script` starts with a basic, default shell without any of your customizations (e.g. .bash_profile, etc).